How to get the largest streak of negative numbers by sum?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [-3, -1, -2, -5, 10, -3, -13, -3, -2, 1, -200, -100],
    }
)

Expected output:
  a
10 -200
11 -100

Logic:
I want to return the largest streak of negative numbers in terms of sum of them. In other words I want AT LEAST two consecutive negative rows and then I want the sum of it to be the largest in terms of absolute value:
My attempt based on this answer:
s = np.sign(df['a'])
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
out = df[g.eq(df[s.eq(-1)].groupby(g).sum().idxmax())]

It gives me an empty dataframe

What is that output? A 2 column dataframe? How did you get the 10 and 11?

@Dogbert it is the largest streak of numbers in terms of sum of the numbers

"I want the sum of it to be the largest". What do you mean by that? The sum of the last streak is -300. That is the lowest. And what should happen in case of a tie?

@ouroboros1 I want the lowest. I`ll edit it.

"My attempt based on this answer:" - okay, and what happens when you try this code? How is that different from the expected result? Did you try to debug this attempt? Where specifically does it appear to go wrong?

@KarlKnechtel it does not work, It gives me an error

But the largest streak by absolute value is -300 like ouroboros1 said which doesn't match your expected output.

@Dogbert it is the largest streak in terms of absolute value.

You should understand very well by now that "it does not work, it gives me an error" is not even close to meeting standards for explaining the problem - and that we expect questions to be more focused than this. The task that you're describing is clearly not something you can expect to be built-in or commonly needed; we don't help people put together steps for a custom algorithm here, as that Needs More Focus.

@KarlKnechtel I had multiple posts like this. I ask the question. I tried. And it failed. So i posted here for more help

Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and note well that this is not a discussion forum. Stack Overflow is not interested in making your project work; it is interested in answering useful questions (= can help someone else who finds it with a search engine), one at a time.

@KarlKnechtel I know the rules here. maybe this question was not well formatted. But I got very good feedback with my other posts

Transform instead of aggregating, and then you can use that to filter the lowest sum.
s = np.sign(df['a'])
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(g).transform(sum)['a']
l = g.groupby(g).transform(len)
out = df[m[l > 1].min() == m]

      a
10 -200
11 -100


This doesn't filter out streaks of length 1, and it will show multiple streaks in case of a tie (the OP didn't answer my question on what should happen in such a case).
